# boost.mpi empty vector message

Tags: mpi, boost-mpi

What will happen if I send an empty vector in Boost MPI?

For example, if I sent using the following code:

```
vector<int> empty_vector;
vector<int> other_vector(1,1);

if (world.rank()==0)
    world.isend(1,10,empty_vector);
if (world.rank()==1)
    world.recv(0,10,other_vector);
```

Would this work? Would it just receive an empty vector and assign it to `other_vector`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping to get a quick response on this, but I didn't. So I went ahead and just tested it. You can send an empty vector as a message. After sending, rank 1 had an empty vector for `other_vec` and rank 1 had the original `other_vec` of size 1.